# Android compressing with different quality doesn't work

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

When I change quality from 100 to 0 (any value) bitmap size before compressing and after always has the same size. Why? And how to really compress it?

```
public static void checkSize(Bitmap tempBitmap, Context context) {
    Log.d("IMAGES_", "SIZE before = " + tempBitmap.getByteCount());
    Bitmap newBit = compress(tempBitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 3);
    Log.d("IMAGES_", "SIZE after = " + newBit.getByteCount());
}

public static Bitmap compress(Bitmap src, Bitmap.CompressFormat format,
                            int quality) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    src.compress(format, quality, os);
    byte[] array = os.toByteArray();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
}
```

**Result:**

- D/IMAGES_: SIZE before = 1228800
- D/IMAGES_: SIZE after = 1228800

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/imageio/compress-a-jpeg-file/

Comment: Thanks, but ImageIO is not supported in Android SDK

Comment: oh yeah, right. my bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are measuring wrong. The compressed size is given by array.length. You are then decoding it back into its full size and pixel encoding. If you want to have a smaller memory footprint, you would need to:

1. resize the image.
2. decode with a different pixel format.
3. all of the above.

Comment: Thanks, But I need to change it with the same image dimensions. And I really do not understand why the method has "quality" argument that never works.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for Bitmap.compress, it explicitly says that some formats will ignore the quality parameter, such as PNG which you use.

Answer (score 1):

1. The quality parameter doesn't work for PNG format which is loseless, you need to change it to JPG to make it take effect.
2. Even you changed it to JPG, the before and after bitmaps will still have the same dimensions, but different qualities. I think what you really need is to call Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() to get a smaller bitmap and then store it.